# Do not delete a record when I run the delete command in sql (in Python and Mysql)

Tags: python, sqlcommand

The following code was run without error, but the database does not affect.
This means that the record can not be deleted.
Part of code in Python

```
import MySQLdb as msdb
def delete_row(self):
    con = msdb.connect('localhost','root','24434','matab_db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    qq = "DELETE FROM tbl_rezerv_nobat WHERE id=4"
    # or qq = "DELETE FROM tbl_rezerv_nobat WHERE id='4'"
    bb = cur.execute(qq)
    con.close()
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a `commit`? If you're using a transaction based database then you will need to commit your queries to get them to actually happen. Sorry, I've not used msdb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also add `con.commit()` before `con.close()`

ie

```
def delete_row(self):
    con = msdb.connect('localhost','root','24434','matab_db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    qq = "DELETE FROM tbl_rezerv_nobat WHERE id=4;"
    # or qq = "DELETE FROM tbl_rezerv_nobat WHERE id='4'"
    bb = cur.execute(qq)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```